# Any image datasets with Inter-annotator agreement (IAA) values recorded?

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, computer-vision, object-detection

Is anyone familiar with publicly accessible image datasets that include Inter-annotator agreement (IAA) scores? Ideally for object detection or classification tasks.

Thank you!